# Load Vue components async on Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have some `javascript` to run in a `blade` file but it is waiting for a `Vue` component to fully load before running.

```
...
<p id="a"></p>
<my-vue-component></my-vue-component>
...
<script>
  document.getElementById('a').innerText = 'ggg'
</script>
```

The javascript code waits for the `Vue` component to load and then it executes.

I don't want the `Vue` component pausing the rest of the javascript. I want it to load while the rest of the javascript executes or to load after the javascript finishes executing.

I tried installing the dynamic import plugin for async rendering

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

and registering it in .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

and running the compiler

```
npm run watch
```

And then in the `app.js` where the components are registered

```
Vue.component('my-vue-component', () => import('./components/MyVueComponent.vue').default);
```

That didn't do what I was expecting

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: The JS code I want to run before the Vue component is *out* of the component, i.e. it doesn't belong to the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the javascript you want to load before or during the loading of vue components is related to the vue component itself, then go for the solution posted by @matticusatrd. If you want the javascript executed before loading any vue components, place it in the `<head>` of your page before your `app.js`.

Beware, this will make the entire page load wait for the javascript code to execute. Additionally you won't have the dom available yet, so you might need to listen to an event like `DOMContentLoaded` before doing any manipulations to the page.

Answer (score 0):

To run some JavaScript after a Vue component is loaded, you can simply add it to the `mounted()` method.

```js
export default {
    name: "MyVueComponent",
    ...
    mounted() {
        // everything here runs after the component is loaded
        let a = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want my JS to run *before* or during the loading of the Vue component, but no after. IMPORTANT NOTE: The JS I want to run is not in the Vue component, it's out of it, in the page that hosts the component

Comment: Then your post is very confusing.  You said, "...Vue component has to **fully load** before that javascript runs".  Now you're saying it can run before?  That makes no sense.

Comment: You're right, that was a poor wording on my part. I just fixed that

Comment: Then you should probably consider using the method @PtrTon mentioned.  But the example JavaScript you provided requires the DOM to be loaded to work correctly, meaning you'll still have to delay the execution until after the Vue component is loaded if you want any links in the Vue component to be included in whatever you are doing — you can't get elements that haven't been written to the DOM yet.

Comment: You're right. The Vue component is part of the DOM and any Javascript after it must wait for the Vue component to render before it can run. So, @PtrTon is basically on the point. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Well, It will not wait because vue js compile and then generate DOM. A better way to perform any action after vue js load is to use the mounted or created methods of Vue Component class.

```
export default{
    name: 'TestComponent',
    mounted(){
        //
    },
    created(){
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: The `created` method won't have rendered the HTML yet.